# Jquery get information from dynamicly added row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have setup a function to add rows to a table and sets values to input fields. My code to add rows is as follows:

```
$('#addItem').click(function() {
$('#itemData tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td align="left"><input id="ItemName[]" name="ItemName[]" type="hidden" value="'+$('#itemName').val()+'">'+$('#itemName').val()+'</td><td align="left"><input id="ItemNombre[]" name="ItemNombre[]" type="hidden" value="'+$('#itemNombre').val()+'">'+$('#itemNombre').val()+'</td><td><div id="editItem" onClick="editItem(this);">edit</div> / delete</td></tr>');
 var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent()) - 1;
 $('#itemName').val('');
 $('#itemNombre').val('');
})
```

I would like to be able to click on "edit" for a particular row and retrieve the values of `ItemName[]` and `ItemNombre[]`. [Here is a JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jecker/ae4duLgq/14/)

Comment: i think you need to share complete code for better understanding . may be a working demo or a jsfiddle will be great!!

Comment: You can't have duplicate "id"s in your HTML. If you press add button more than once ; then you will have 2 elements with the same id which is not a good practice.

Comment: use common classes instead of ID

Comment: duplicate ids are now allowed in HTML5

Comment: ArGh if you are referring to ItemName[] being used more than once when the row is added, PHP uses this naming structure as an array and allows me to step through the values.

Comment: I was responding to vijayP about the duplicated ids. PHP used the name attribute with [ ] to make your array so your id="ItemName[]" can be removed and you should use a class name instead (class="itemname") and then call jquery event with this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the onClick="editItem(this);" call.

Then, add a function like this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#editItem', function(){
    // Get your datas
    var $this = $(this),
        ItemNombre = $this.parent().parent().find('#ItemNombre').val(),
        ...;
    // Do your stuff
    // ...
});
```

Comment: How can I reference back this same item from a different function?

Comment: In the "do your stuff ...", when you call your other function, you can pass $this as argument of the function target your item.